# Magento Shopping cart: products not showing up

Tags: magento, cart

Magento version 1.8
Problem appears after upgrade from version 1.5

In checkout/cart.phtml there is code:

```
<?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
  <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

**$this->getItemHtml($_item)** should render template /cart/item/default.phtml but it doesn't!

i change it to:

```
<?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
      <?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
```

And It really shows the product id which i bought

Why it doesn't renders the template?

Comment: check file exits or not: template\checkout\cart\item\default.phtml

Comment: all needed files exists

Comment: OK, Enable [system/exception].log from Sytem->Configuration->Developer->Log Settings and see if there is any thing helpful if there is nothing then debug default.phtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved**
The problem was in Artio M-Turbo extension (for caching)

It automatically turns off after upgrade and somehow affects cart items template.

So, if you have same problem and Artio MTurbo installed,
try to enabled it in **System -> Configuration -> Advanced** (module output)
and don't forget to clear cache